# What is the meaning of "with easy to understand graphs" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "with easy to understand graphs" in the following sentence,

> The Performance tab provides great information on how
>   your computer's hardware is performing ***with easy to understand graphs***
>   . (source: How to use Windows
>   10 Task Manager to monitor system performance  by Mauro Huculak )

Does "with easy to understand graphs" mean "great information is easy to understand graphs" ?
Does "with" mean "great information is" ?

Answer (score 2):

The performance tab uses **graphs that are *easy to understand*** (that functioning as an adjective phrase, and might be rendered easy-to-understand to avoid confusion) to **provide great information**.

If you treat "easy to understand" as an adjective, and remove it, the sentence is easier to read. Then put it back in, and see that it modifies *graphs*.